# No break between span tags in th

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with sorting arrows in the table header. Each `th` element has a `span` for text and a `span` for the sorting arrows. I want the text in the left `span` to wrap dynamically and the `span` with the sorting arrows to stay in the top right of the `th`.

CSS:

```css
th {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.sort {
    float: right;
}
.sort-arrow {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
}
.sort-arrow.asc {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #1F2B39;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    margin-top: 3px;
}
.sort-arrow.desc {
    border-top: 5px solid #1F2B39;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <span>A pretty pretty pretty pretty pretty pretty pretty pretty pretty pretty pretty pretty pretty pretty pretty pretty pretty pretty long text.</span>
                <span class="sort">
                    <div class="sort-arrow asc"></div>
                    <div class="sort-arrow desc"></div>
                </span>
            </th>
            <th>
                <span>Short</span>
                <span class="sort">
                    <div class="sort-arrow asc"></div>
                    <div class="sort-arrow desc"></div>
                </span>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Test</td><td>Test</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Test</td><td>Test</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: IDs still need to be _unique_ ...

Comment: change id to class , so that style will apply to both

Comment: Changed id to class. It was a copy/paste error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a div inside th and give that div a display of flex, and for the elements ot go to the top of th you can use vertical-align: top;

```css
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align:left;
}

thead,
tbody {
  background: yellow;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}



.sort-arrow {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
}

.sort-arrow.asc {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #1F2B39;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.sort-arrow.desc {
  border-top: 5px solid #1F2B39;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr >
      <th>
        <div class="row">
          <span>A pretty pretty pretty pretty pretty pretty pretty pretty pretty pretty pretty pretty pretty pretty pretty pretty pretty pretty long text.</span>
          <span class="sort">
                    <div class="sort-arrow asc"></div>
                    <div class="sort-arrow desc"></div>
                </span>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th >
      <div class="row">
        <span>Short</span>
        <span class="sort">
                    <div class="sort-arrow asc"></div>
                    <div class="sort-arrow desc"></div>
                </span>
                </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried this and also put flex on td but now it's not a table structure anymore. It's just rows without arranged columns.

Comment: Added a TBODY in my question.

Comment: just edited the asnwer, setting the display of th to flex messes up the table structure, so create a div inside th and set that div's display to flex instead.

Answer (score 1):

Using `position: relative` on the parent and `position: absolute` on the children should do the job. Then you can place them by using `top: 0` and `right: 0` and it will put them in the top-right corner !

In order to have the text wrapping, simply make your containers a fix width (ou with percentages), the text will wrap because it is it's natural way of working.

And as @CBroe said in the comment, ID's have to be unique !

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This worked with a few tweeks, but the accepted answer gave me the least changes to my code.

Answer (score 0):

*Updated to show example using CSS Grid table layout*

You can easily use `display: flex` with `justify-content: space-between`.  You can also use the `gap` property as shown in the example below to give some white-space between the title and the arrows.

```css
table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(30ch, auto) 1fr;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  margin: 0 -1px -1px 0; /* hack to collapse borders */
  padding: 1rem;
}

tr:last-of-type > td {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #aaa;
}

thead,
tbody, 
tr {
  display: contents;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.sort-arrow {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
}

.sort-arrow.asc {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #1F2B39;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.sort-arrow.desc {
  border-top: 5px solid #1F2B39;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <div class="header">
          <span>A pretty pretty pretty pretty pretty pretty pretty pretty pretty pretty pretty pretty pretty pretty pretty pretty pretty pretty long text.</span>
          <span class="sort">
            <div class="sort-arrow asc"></div>
            <div class="sort-arrow desc"></div>
          </span>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div class="header">
          <span>Short</span>
          <span class="sort">
            <div class="sort-arrow asc"></div>
            <div class="sort-arrow desc"></div>
          </span>
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried this and also put flex on td but now it's not a table structure anymore. It's just rows without arranged columns.

Comment: Added a TBODY in my question.